# How can you flush a write using a file descriptor?

Tags: c, linux, stdio, i2c

> It turns out this whole misunderstanding of the open() versus fopen() stems from a buggy I2C driver in the Linux 2.6.14 kernel on an ARM.  Backporting a working bit bashed driver solved the root cause of the problem I was trying to address here.

I'm trying to figure out an issue with a serial device driver in Linux (I2C).  It appears that by adding timed OS pauses (sleeps) between writes and reads on the device things work ... (much) better.

> Aside: *The nature of I2C is that each byte read or written by the master is acknowledged by the device on the other end of the wire (slave) - the pauses improving things encourage me to think of the driver as working asynchronously - something that I can't reconcile with how the bus works.  Anyhoo ...*

I'd either like to **flush** the write to be sure (rather than using fixed duration pause), ***or*** somehow test that the write/read transaction has **completed** in an multi-threaded friendly way.

The trouble with using `fflush(fd);` is that it requires 'fd' to be stream pointer (not a file descriptor) i.e.

```
FILE * fd = fopen("filename","r+");
... // do read and writes
fflush(fd);
```

My problem is that I require the use of the `ioctl()`, which doesn't use a stream pointer. i.e.

```
int fd = open("filename",O_RDWR);
ioctl(fd,...);
```

Suggestions?

Comment: In user-land code, the write() function is automatically non-buffered.  You don't need to flush it -- it is self-flushing.  Indeed, unless you use special system calls, it is also synchronous with device driver.

Comment: If you are writing a kernel-level module, the rules may be somewhat different, but then you should probably be using the file descriptor i/o and not standard (file pointer) i/o.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You have two choices:

1. Use `fileno()` to obtain the file descriptor associated with the `stdio` stream pointer
2. Don't use `<stdio.h>` at all, that way you don't need to worry about flush either - all writes will go to the device immediately, and for character devices the `write()` call won't even return until the lower-level IO has completed (in theory).

For device-level IO I'd say it's pretty unusual to use `stdio`.  I'd strongly recommend using the lower-level `open()`, `read()` and `write()` functions instead (based on your later reply):

```
int fd = open("/dev/i2c", O_RDWR);
ioctl(fd, IOCTL_COMMAND, args);
write(fd, buf, length);
```

Comment: Avoiding <stdio.h> is what I've been doing; the "Aside" in my original post led me to thinking that the file descriptors _might_ have been buffered.  Thanks for confirming that they aren't and that I should be looking for another reason pummelling the I2C bus causes trouble.

Comment: Let's make the terminology clear - a UNIX file descriptor is an integer index and is supposed to be unbuffered so that a call to write/read is immediate.  It is supposed to be very efficient for "large" writes and inefficient for single byte writes. fopen gives you buffered I/O. Use open/read/write.

Answer (score 46):

I think what you are looking for may be

```
int fsync(int fd);
```

or

```
int fdatasync(int fd);
```

`fsync` will flush the file from kernel buffer to the disk. `fdatasync` will also do except for the meta data.

Comment: The OP stated this is an i2c character device, not a disk.

Comment: Ok, i2c dev nodes are not page-buffered so it does not need to be flushed/sync'ed. The fops in device driver determine what are actually done.

Comment: Though this is not the solution to the OP's question, it is useful to others asking the main title question. I **am** writing to a disk via an fd, so it was very helpful to see how to flush the kernel buffers.

Answer (score 13):

`fflush()` only flushes the buffering added by the stdio `fopen()` layer, as managed by the `FILE *` object. The underlying file itself, as seen by the kernel, is not buffered at this level. This means that writes that bypass the `FILE *` layer, using `fileno()` and a raw `write()`, are also not buffered in a way that `fflush()` would flush.

As others have pointed out, try **not** mixing the two. If you need to use "raw" I/O functions such as `ioctl()`, then `open()` the file yourself directly, **without** using `fopen<()` and friends from stdio.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried disabling buffering?

```
setvbuf(fd, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm not sure what my setup is, but I used this and "fsync" (using fileno to get the int instead of a FILE*) and I was able to seek and read from the file after closing and reopening it.

Comment: This only works for fopen() and not for open(). The original question asks about disabling buffering for open() call.

Comment: `open()` has no buffer, it goes straight to the device driver.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the fsync() function (or fdatasync()?), or you could use the O_SYNC flag in your open() call.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to go the other way round (associate FILE* with existing file descriptor), use fdopen() :

```
                                                          FDOPEN(P)

NAME

       fdopen - associate a stream with a file descriptor

SYNOPSIS

       #include <stdio.h>

       FILE *fdopen(int fildes, const char *mode);
```